# Converting numpy.ndarray into opencv cv::Mat

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy, boost-python

I have Boost-Python interface for C++ OpenCv. I am getting this error when I invoke a C++ method from python:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Vision.process(Vision, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)
did not match C++ signature:
    process(python::vision::PythonVision {lvalue}, cv::Mat {lvalue}, cv::Mat {lvalue})
```

I am using python cv2.so module. How do I convert numpy.ndarray into cv::mat?

Comment: No idea, but there's any reason why you're not using official bindings?

Comment: I am using C++ openCV to build an android library. I built python bindings to  interface with C++ code for fast prototyping. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following project:https://github.com/Algomorph/pyboostcvconverter and statically linked to it.

Note (To avoid segmentation fault):

1) PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL should be defined where import_array is invoked
In other places where  is included, use NO_IMPORT_ARRAY

```
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL PYVISION_ARRAY_API
#include <pyboostcvconverter/pyboostcvconverter.hpp>
```

2) Invoke init_ar from the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE

```
/**
 * @brief Initialize Numpy Array
 */
static void init_ar( )
{
    // initialize
    Py_Initialize();

    // defined in numpy
    import_array();
}
```